# Installing Seurat - R toolkit for single cell genomics

Tags: r, git, seurat

I am new to R and trying to install Seurat to analyze my genomic single cell data. I want to use Seurat (http://www.satijalab.org/install.html), however, having difficulty installing the package. My order of operations is as follows:

1. Install R (successful)
2. Install "devtools" package from Hadley Wickham (successful)

(Entered the following commands):

```
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
```

3. Install Seurat - directly from Github (unsuccessful):

(Attempted to enter the following commands):

```
install_github("satijalab/seurat")
library(Seurat)
```

...When I try to install Seurat from github, I receive the following error message:

Downloading github repo satijalab/seurat@master
Error in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib) : 
  shared object ‘stringi.so’ not found

...I have looked on this forum, as well as google, to fix this problem, however, I have not had much luck. Any help would be greatly appreciate!

Thank you,
Marc

Comment: Try reading this http://statbits.blogspot.com/2015/06/installing-reshape2-package-into-r-on.html ; see if you can install the stringi package.

Answer (score 1):

I just installed Seurant with cran and no errors. Make sure you are running R 3.4 or higher.

```
install.packages('Seurat')
library(Seurat)
```

On their [website](https://satijalab.org/seurat/install.html) they only install through github_install for the prerelease or development version. If you haven't checked out their website, they have some nice guided tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

From a R that has never installed `seurat` I can attest that the codes you are using are correct.

```
> library(devtools)
> install_github("satijalab/seurat")
Downloading github repo satijalab/seurat@master
Installing Seurat
Installing 23 packages: ape, corpcor, DEoptimR, diptest, fastICA, flexmix, fpc, jackstraw, kernlab, lars, mclust, mixtools, modeltools, prabclus, robustbase, ROCR, Rtsne, segmented, trimcluster, tsne, useful, VGAM, XLConnectJars
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  cannot open URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/XLConnectJars_0.2-9.zip'
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The operation timed out'
Warning in download.packages(pkgs, destdir = tmpd, available = available,  :
  download of package ‘XLConnectJars’ failed
package ‘ape’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘corpcor’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘DEoptimR’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘diptest’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘fastICA’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘flexmix’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘fpc’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘jackstraw’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘kernlab’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘lars’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘mclust’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘mixtools’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘modeltools’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘prabclus’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘robustbase’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘ROCR’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘Rtsne’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘segmented’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘trimcluster’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘tsne’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘useful’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘VGAM’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.1/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore CMD INSTALL  \
  "C:/Users/Riorank/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpSwBkRW/devtools200c34282ec7/satijalab-seurat-a0b8594"  \
  --library="C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.1/library" --install-tests 

* installing *source* package 'Seurat' ...
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (Seurat)
>
```

With this said have you considered using `installed.packages()`and `remove.packages()` to manually delete (assumed) previous version of seurat?

Answer (score 0):

I installed SEURAT a couple of weeks ago on two Debian machines and there are the packages I had to install to make it work properly:

gcc 4.9 at least
rJAVA
libssl-dev
plotutils

These package have to be installed outside R (i.e. with apt-get or whatever you use on your system).